# AVAudioPlayer with extremely long duration (for ~10 second file)

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, duration

When playing a file with an AVAudioPlayer (loaded from NSData) I am accessing the 'duration' property as specified by apple's docs like this:

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.audioData error:&local_error];
NSLog(@"%f",player.duration);
```

However the duration spits out 268435.199875 for a less than 10 second file.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Duration is an `NSTImeInterval`, which is `double`.

Comment: True... however the docs say that "Returns the total duration, in seconds, of the sound associated with the audio player" which I assume to mean the double is the number of seconds the file contains. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Try %e in the NSLog, may not matter. Check your error value, may just not be loading properly.

Comment: Doing that produces 2.684352e+05. I'm still a bit confused, is there an extra step I need to do to convert between the double I am receiving and the total length of the clip ins econds?